# Split data.frame by factor into list, then turn the list into matrix with xtabs and drop all unused levels?

Tags: r, matrix, split, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a relatively large dataset of ecological networks (plant x animal interactions). Ultimately, I want to split the dataset into a series of lists by a factor (e.g., site), and run analyses on each of these mini networks. The data look something like this for example:

```
site<-c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C")
animal<-c("bee", "bee", "fly", "bird", "bee", "fly", "fly", "fly", "bird", "bird", "bee", "fly")
plant<-c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "purple", "green", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "red", "yellow")
interactions<-c(4, 9, 5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 5, 10, 9, 2, 12)

df<-data.frame(site, animal, plant, interactions)
```

I first split the data.frame by "site" into a series of lists, which I have done using split()

```
dl<-split(df, df$site)
```

I then convert each of these lists into a matrix with plants and animals as rows and columns and the contents of the matrix as the sum of interactions between each plant and animal. I have achieved this using lapply() and xtabs():

```
ml<-lapply(dl, function(x) xtabs(x$interactions ~ x$animal + x$plant))
```

But...when I do this, each and every plant and animal in the entire data.frame are included in each individual matrix, which I do not want for a variety of reasons. This is clear when looking at str(ml). I have tried remove the unused plants and animals in each individual matrix using lapply() and factor(), but this has not worked.

How can I efficiently convert the data.frame from each site in the list into a matrix with only the plants and animals present at that site? For example, I would like the site "A" matrix to look like this:

```
          plant
  animal  blue  red 
    bee     0    13
    bird    7     0 
    fly     5     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

```
ml <- lapply(dl, function(x) xtabs(interactions~animal+plant, droplevels(x)))

ml[[1]]
#       plant
#animal blue red
# bee     0  13
# bird    7   0
# fly     5   0
```